# How to access the AWS public dataset using Databrick?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, databricks, aws-databricks

I am new to databricks. I am looking for public big data dataset for my school project, then I came across AWS public dataset on this link: https://registry.opendata.aws/target/

I am using python on Databricks, and I don't know how to establish a connection to the data. I have found the following how to guide:

https://databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Databricks-how-to-data-import.pdf?_ga=2.25033139.881714623.1602433762-982722630.1598480448

It mentioned [image: Screenshot]

I am not sure how to find the respective access_key, secret_key, AWS_bucket_name and the mount_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation is for non-public S3 buckets.

For this dataset you can simply read using the `s3://...` URL, like this:

```py
df = spark.read.format("text").load("s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open/")
```

I used `text` file format just for example, but because this dataset uses XML to store the data, you'll need to use something like [spark-xml library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) to extract necessary data.